# Java 8 streams.reduce() with combiner

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My question is that i would like a breakdown of the following code

I have a map and i want to replace certain strings with the map's value with the following reduce() function:

```
Map<String, String> environmentMap = new HashMap<>();

Function<String, String> replaceFunction = environmentMap.entrySet()
.stream()
.reduce
(Function.identity(),
(function,entrySet) -> stringToReplace -> function.apply(stringToReplace.replaceAll(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue(),
Function::andThen);
```

Somehow i'm confused on the replaceFunction part but let me break it down based on my understanding.

1. The line `environmentMap.entrySet().stream()` will create a stream of `Entry<String,String>`.
2. The `reduce()` method that i am using takes an identity, accumulator, and a combiner.
3. Since i am not using a parallel stream i thought of omitting the combiner, but then the compiler throws an error. Is there any way that i could transform this accumulator into a `BinaryOperator<T>`?
4. `Function.identity()` will always return a Function that returns the input argument. In this case of type `String`
5. The second argument which intakes a BiFunction is one of the things i'm confused with. `(function,entrySet) -> stringToReplace -> function.apply(stringToReplace.replaceAll(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue()`.
6. What does Function::andThen do in this process?
7. Lastly, where did the return type `Function<String,String>` in the `BiFunction<T, U, R>` came from??

Answer (score 1):

```
Function<String, String> replaceFunction = environmentMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .reduce(Function.identity(),
                    (function,entrySet) -> stringToReplace -> function.apply(stringToReplace.replaceAll(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue())),
                            Function::andThen);
```

1. The line `environmentMap.entrySet().stream()` will create a stream of `Entry<String,String>`.
2. The `reduce()` method that i am using takes an *identity, accumulator, and a combiner.item*.

   Till this you are right, but the *identity, accumulator, and combiner* gets resolved as follows:

   - *identity* - `Function.identity()` gets resolved to `Function<String, String>`.
   - *accumulator* - `(function,entrySet) -> stringToReplace -> function.apply(stringToReplace.replaceAll(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue()))`.

     Here the following part,

     ```
     `stringToReplace -> function.apply(stringToReplace.replaceAll(entrySet.getKey(),entrySet.getValue()))`
     ```

     gets resolved into `Function<String, String>`.

     And so this entire accumulator gets resolved to

     ```
     `BiFunction<Function<String,String>, Entry<String,String>,Function<String,String>`
     ```
   - *combiner* - `Function::andThen` gets resolved to `BinaryOperator<Function<String,String>, Function<String,String>>`

So, to answer your question in 6 and 7, `Function::andThen` acts as the combiner; and 7 is the accumulator as I described above.